# PHPStorm - Force array() String Declaration With Code Style

Tags: phpstorm, phpstorm-2017.2

In PHPStorm, you can force arrays to be declared as `[]` in the "Code Style" section of Settings.

[image]

Is there anyway to do the opposite and force arrays to be declared with `array()`?  For example, I would like the following:

`$myArray = ['one', 'two'];`

to become

`$myArray = array('one', 'two');`

when I reformat a script using the editor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an Intention for this: 
[image: convert array]

Unfortunately there's no way to have it performed automatically on "reformat code".